# How to calculate the number of unique patterns in a 3x3 grid using 4 different elements

Tags: combinatorics, tiling

I have a 3x3 grid (9 cells) I would like to populate with 4 different elements (e.g., colors or shapes or numbers, etc.) in four of the cells. How many different unique patterns can I generate with the four elements? By "unique" I mean that the patterns are not a symmetrical doubles of other patterns. Is there a way to calculate this? Trying to manually count the possibilities is too tedious and error prone and the math seems to be beyond me.

Comment: Your definition of "unique" needs to be fleshed out more clearly as it is not the usual definition. I'm not sure what you mean by "symmetrical doubles of other patterns."

Comment: Example of a symmetry: Four cells in a nine cell grid can create an "L" shaped pattern. That shape can be rotated or flipped to occupy different cells but it is still the same "L" shape and should be counted only once.

Answer (score 0):

If all your pieces are different from one another, then it's impossible to make any symmetric configuration - since every symmetry of the square fixes at most three cells, we'll always have at least one piece in a cell not fixed by that symmetry.

So every arrangement you come up with will have all $8$ possible rotations and reflections, without any repeats. This means that it's very easy to correct for overcounting, since we can just divide the total number of arrangements by $8$:

$$\frac{9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6}{8} = 9\cdot7\cdot6 =388$$